# In Python multiprocessing, why is child process name __mp_main__? Is there a way to override it with a custom name?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing as mp


def child_process():
    print('Hi! My name is', __name__)


print('Hi! My name is', __name__)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.Process(target=child_process).start()
```

The above code output it as below:
[image: Console output from the above code]

I am confused about

1. Why is the child process name `__mp_main__`?
2. Why is it printed twice?

Comment: I assume the name is an implementation detail, the main issue is that it cannot be called `__main__`. As for why it's printed twice, because there are two processes. The first one is from the master process, the second one is from when the child process loads the script, and the third print is from when the child process executed `child_process()`

Comment: I thought so too - that first one is while loading and second one is while executing - but it doesn't make sense. What if I want code inside the child process to be be execute only once. Also, when I comment out the p1.start() only the name for master process is printed, i.e. __main__

Comment: " but it doesn't make sense. What if I want code inside the child process to be be execute only once." **then you must put it behind the `if __name__ == "__main__": ...` guard**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga hey is this behaviour different in python `3.8.5`? I ran this code and both the child's and main's `__name__` value is `__main__`. 
Also the child process didn't execute the `top-level` print, only the target function it is supposed to execute.
https://www.online-python.com/SnKYw3Ubry

Answer (score 6):

You are confusing yourself because you're printing the same message in two different places. If you give distinct printouts, you'll understand better what is going on:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def child_process():
    print('Function print from:', __name__)

print('Top level print from:', __name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.Process(target=child_process).start()
```

With this code, you'll get:

```
Top level print from: __main__
Top level print from: __mp_main__
Function print from: __mp_main__
```

Now you can see that the first printout is from the main module running the top level code. Then the child process is launched, and it also runs the top level code. Then the multiprocessing logic runs the function inside the child process, and you get the third line.

It may come as a surprise that the module is loaded again in the child process, but it's part of the design of Python's multiprocessing when using the `spawn` mode (which is the default). The top level code runs again, but not the part guarded by `if __name__ == "__main__"`, since `__name__` is `__mp_main__`. The different name is deliberate, to prevent *all* the code (including launching another child) from running again in the child process. Having each child also spawn another process would do bad things to your system, since you'd be creating an unlimited number of processes.

Another thing worth understanding: The `__name__` global variable isn't the name of the process, it's the name of the current module. If you were to `import` the module containing the code above, it would print out the actual module name, rather than either `__main__` or `__mp_main__`, which are special names used for the module being run as a script, and the same module in a child process, respectively. [Dan Constantinescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12189257/dan-constantinescu) has given a good answer explaining how to print out the actual process name, if you want that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a name for the child process by using the `name` argument. Also you can use the `current_process().name` to better identify which process is running and to display its name:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def child_process():
    print('Hi! My name is', mp.current_process().name)


print('Hi! My name is', mp.current_process().name)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.Process(target=child_process, name="child process").start()
```

Processes create their own memory space and as indicated in the comment, the prints are from: main process, child process loading the script and then child process executing `child_process()` function. If you do the same but with threads, you will see only two prints as threads share the same memory space:

```
import threading


def child_thread():
    print('Hi! My name is', threading.current_thread().name)


print('Hi! My name is', threading.current_thread().name)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=child_thread, name="Child thread").start()
```