# Multiprocessing pool in a Python class without __name__ == "__main__" guard

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing

I am attempting to run a multiprocessed job within a larger Python class. In a simple form, the class looks as following:

```
class Thing:
    def test(self):
        with mp.Pool() as p:
            yield from p.map(str, range(20))
```

When I import this class to a script such as:

```
from x import Thing

t = Thing()
for item in t.test():
    print(item)
```

I run into the commonly known issue:

```
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

My question is, how do I guard against this behaviour, without requiring the user of my class to write

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

every time they run my class function? Is there a way of performing this inside the class definition?

I have tried writing

```
from x import Thing

t = Thing()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for item in t.test():
        print(item)
```

which solves the issue, but I do not want this to be the way a user interfaces this class.

Comment: Multi-processing explicitly sets the requirement and you are using the multi-processing library. Accept the requirement.

Comment: I would suggest it is better instead to possibly attempt to catch the `RuntimeError` and provide some additional information to the user before re-raising the exception. Preventing your code from executing unintentionally during import is important for more than just `multiprocessing`, but can cause problems with any sort of shared resources as well such as IO. It's a prime recipe for race conditions and hard-to-trace bugs. It is more strictly enforced with multiprocessing, but always good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the value of `__name__` in the main module of a spawned child process is `'__mp_main__'` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72497140/in-python-multiprocessing-why-is-child-process-name-mp-main-is-there-a-way), you can place a guard in the function that spawns child processes by checking if any of the ancestors' frames has a `__name__` in the global namespace with a value of `'__mp_main__'`, in which case the current process is a child and the execution should stop so that no more child would be spawned:

```
# x.py
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp

class Thing:
    def test(self):
        frame = sys._getframe(1)
        while frame:
            if frame.f_globals['__name__'] == '__mp_main__':
                return
            frame = frame.f_back
        with mp.Pool() as p:
            yield from p.map(str, range(20))
```

EDIT: An even easier way to guard against a child process is to validate that the current process name is [`'MainProcess'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.log_to_stderr):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Thing:
    def test(self):
        if mp.current_process().name == 'MainProcess':
            with mp.Pool() as p:
                yield from p.map(str, range(20))
```

Comment: Interesting solution - but a bigger problem remains. Everything in the top script is executed in each worker process, not just the pool call. Add `print("only do this once")` to the main script and you'll see it multiple times.